# Division as repeated subtraction based on another function?

Tags: python, loops, math

How can I use the "subtraction()" function into the division() function in a for/while loop to make a division operation based on repeated subtractions, giving the quotient as well as the remainder? Thank you. Here is my code so far:

```
def subtraction(x, y): #subtraction function
    return x - y

def division(x, y): #division function
    repeatsub = 0
    for i in range(y):
        repeat = subtraction(repeatsub, 2)
    return repeatsub
```

Comment: What have you tried to solve this problem. By the looks of it, this is its first iteration and since it, doesn't work, you just posted it on SO. Please do make _every effort_ to debug your own code. This website isn't a debugging tool, especially for such simple tasks

Answer (score 1):

Division is writing a number into the form:
`x=ay+b` where `b<y`. So you should repeatedly subtract y from x, while the `result>=y`. The final result is the remainder. The quotient is the number of calls made, you can do it like `quotient=0` and `quotient=quotient+1` after each subtraction.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I find to do it is according to this [guide](https://www.splashlearn.com/math-vocabulary/subtraction/repeated-subtraction#:%7E:text=Repeated%20subtraction%20is%20a%20method,in%20the%20form%20of%20division.) which substracts x from y until 0 is reached.

Try this code:

```
def subtraction(x, y): #subtraction function
    return x - y

def division(x, y): #division function
    if (y==0):
        return -1 #ZeroDivisionError
    repeatsub = 0
    while (x>y):
        x = subtraction(x, y)
        repeatsub +=1
    return repeatsub
```

which for this main script:

```
x=13
y=2
print(division(x,y))
```

prints `6` as expected.

I also suggest to take care of the special case of division by zero, where in this example I return -1 but you can change use any other solution that fits you.

The while condition `x>y` makes sure we still need to substract, if you are sure that it is an integer division you can change it to `x>0`

Note: My solution also works when `y` is greater than `x` which makes it elegant and simple.

Answer (score 0):

This performs integer division and returns the quotient and the remainder.

```
def subtraction(x, y): # Subtraction function
    return x - y

def division(x, y): # Division function
    if y == 0:
        raise ZeroDivisionError
    quotient = 0
    remainder = x
    while remainder >= y:
        remainder = subtraction(remainder, y) # or remainder -= y
        quotient += 1
    return (quotient, remainder)

print("Quotient and remainder are", division(10, 2))
```

Output:

```
Quotient and remainder are (5, 0)
```